# how to extract a part of a line after delimiter using awk programming and print it to output?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, extract

I want to extract `911116683` and `USCAFARES` and also display the name of input file which I am processing using awk. the string is: `'/split/911116683/1Y/USCAFARES'`  .

My awk program is :

```
awk -F" " 'BEGIN { OFS="|"; FILE_NAME="NULL"; WU_SG="NULL"; SRC_FTP_LOG_FILENAME="NULL"; } /Src file:/         { FILE_NAME1=$3; WU_SG1=$3; } END{ FILE_NAME=substr(FILE_NAME1,22,9); WU_SG=substr(FILE_NAME1,9,9); SRC_FTP_LOG_FILENAME=FILENAME; print(FILE_NAME,WU_SG,SRC_FTP_LOG_FILENAME); }' $File_to_be_processed
```

but I am getting syntax error for echo statement, I guess it can't be used. how to extract the fields here inside awk and display using variables?

my input file i.e File_to_be_processed contains this line:

```
Src file: '/split/911116683/1Y/USCAFARES' on host 'Local'
```

my output desired is:

```
USCAFARES|911116683|SYSOUT_0ranv_00007
```

where `SYSOUT_0ranv_00007` is the name of the input file or `File_to_be_processed`

Comment: Don't use all upper case variable names. That's for the awk builtin variables. There is no echo statement in your script - what do you mean by `I am getting syntax error for echo statement`, what is the syntax error, and what part of the code is producing it? Edit your question to clean up and answer those questions, don't respond in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. All I did with your code was add whitespace, remove the needless variable instantiations,  and lowercase the awk variable names to make it less shouty.

```
File_to_be_processed=SYSOUT_0ranv_00007 

cat >$File_to_be_processed <<'END'
Src file: '/split/911116683/1Y/USCAFARES' on host 'Local'
END

awk -F" " '
    BEGIN { OFS = "|" }
    /Src file:/ { file_name1 = $3; wu_sg1 = $3; } 
    END { 
        file_name = substr(file_name1,22,9)
        wu_sg = substr(file_name1,9,9)
        src_ftp_log_filename = FILENAME
        print(file_name,wu_sg,src_ftp_log_filename)
    }
' $File_to_be_processed
```

I would use a different FS to make it easier to grab the bits you want:

```
awk -F "[/']" -v OFS="|" '/Src file:/ {print $6, $4, FILENAME; exit}' $File_to_be_processed
```

Comment: that's pretty okay but what if I also have contents in the input file as:

Comment: Customer:  1Y
Scheduled Run Date: CTMERRgv_d_1Y_date_adhoc
Scheduled Run Time:  CTMERRTM

Comment: and I also need to extract the values of each of these and use to generate report separated by "|"

Comment: desired output will be: 1Y|CTMERRgv_d_1Y_date_adhoc|CTMERRTM|USCAFARES|911116683|SYSOUT_0ranv_00007

Comment: If you have further requirements, you'll need update your question. We can't give you good answers on a moving target.